# What does ^:replace mean in a Leiningen project.clj file?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have a project.clj file derived from someone else's git repo.  There's a line that reads

```
:jvm-opts ^:replace []
```

I know that `:jvm-opts` allows adding java command line options.  What does `^:replace` do?  There is some about it in Leiningen's [profile.md](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md), and it's mentioned in Leiningen's example project file [sample.project.clj](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj), but I still don't understand.  I want to add `"-Xmx1G"` to to jvm-opts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add to the options vector the one you need:

```
:jvm-opts ["-Xmx1g"]
```

If you have more than one:

```
:jvm-opts ["-Xmx1g" "-server"]
```

`replace` can be used in many configuration options where different `map` `sets` or `vectors` are merged.

So in this situation if you want the `jvm-opts` to be *only* the ones you specify use `replace` metadata (otherwise other options may be merged depending on your configuration)